# "muffler" v. "scarf"

Tags: difference

My understanding is that "scarf" refers only to long thick strips of fabric you wrap around your neck in cold weather. "Scarf" can refer both to that and also to those things some women wear for religious/cultural reasons (they may also have their Muslim names, but "scarf" would be a generic European term). Is it correct? If not, what are the differences?

Comment: This isn't about learning English, this is about definitions that could be found in a dictionary and the differences between other European countries and religious cultures.

Comment: @Astralbee I actually checked several dictionaries (five of them)

Comment: Yet your question still got shut down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of these people is wearing a scarf. They are all wearing scarves. The Queen is famous for liking to wear them on her head when outdoors. When they are worn like that, they can be called 'headscarves'. The man on the right, the Fourth [Doctor Who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who), played by the celebrated actor Tom Baker, is wearing a type of scarf which can also be called a 'muffler', especially by people from the Midlands and North of England. My mother from London called it a scarf, and my father from Derby said it was a muffler.

[image]

Comment: Interesting - I'm originally from the North & I've never heard a scarf called a muffler. I honestly thought muffler was an AmEng word, not BrEng.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. - I think it's a bit old-fashioned. Men on Corrie used to talk about wearing a 'flat 'at and muffler' when it was cold, and I have myself heard Yorkshire people say it.

Comment: Yorkshire born & bred, can't recall ever hearing it. Maybe it's one of those that never crossed the Leeds/Castleford divide, like the pronunciation of 'boo-its' for boots etc. [I lived in Leeds, worked in Castleford - it was like crossing a border, linguistically ;)

Comment: @gonefishin'again. - mainly South Yorkshire/north Derbyshire (my dad's area) I suppose. I see there is a book published by the _Yorkshire Dalesman_ magazine called 'Flat Caps & Mufflers - The Art of being a Yorkshireman'. It's a collection of columns  written for that magazine by Ian Macmillan. https://shop.dalesman.co.uk/flat-caps-mufflers.html

Comment: In that case, yup, probably never got North of Castleford. Many things didn't. There's some kind of linguistic divide happens there, like a smaller version of Danelaw, that separates the accents/dialects. I really have no citation for it or know why, but it's there.

Comment: Cue the fanboys telling you that he's called 'The Doctor' and not actually 'Doctor Who'.

Comment: @Astralbee - I did think of that, but given all the circs, decided to err on the side of clarity.